# How to conduct one-step IPD network meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, network-meta-analysis

I am new to meta-analysis... might be a newbie question but I'm wondering if the principles of conducting a one-step network meta-analysis are the same as doing it pairwise? (assuming that patients can be randomized to either arm in the clinical setting)

Is there anything to adjust for?

Are there packages available for this or can this be done with the IPD data on a standard cox-regression model?

Comment: I would use a mixed effect model (either logistic or Cox) with studies as random effects, and treatment comparisons as fixed effects... Also consider reading this for additional guidance: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/305822417_An_overview_of_methods_for_network_meta-analysis_using_individual_participant_data_when_do_benefits_arise